# How to tell if a string contains a certain character in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a page with a textbox where a user is supposed to enter a 24 character (letters and numbers, case insensitive) registration code.  I used `maxlength` to limit the user to entering 24 characters.

The registration codes are typically given as groups of characters separated by dashes, but I would like for the user to enter the codes without the dashes.

How can I write my JavaScript code without jQuery to check that a given string that the user inputs does not contain dashes, or better yet, only contains alphanumeric characters?

Comment: The answer found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192612 has the information on how to validate on alphanumeric.

Comment: And to learn regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: For you jquery folks you should and could use `inArray`.

Comment: How input is formatted is not a human's problem.  It's the computer's problem.  Take whatever the user enters and remove all the characters that don't belong (non-alpha), test to see the result is 24 characters long, then validate it.

User's really hate formatted input.

Answer (score 727, accepted):

To find "hello" in `your_string`

```
if (your_string.indexOf('hello') > -1)
{
  alert("hello found inside your_string");
}
```

For the alpha numeric you can use a regular expression:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

[Alpha Numeric Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336210/regular-expression-for-alphanumeric-and-underscores)

Comment: That was quite helpful. Speaking as a python programmer, I am using that to replace the "in" keyword (which may or may not be unorthodox, I am unsure) but it works for more than just a single character.

Comment: I don't understand how this was voted at the answer. I can see that a lot of people come here by Googling. A better way would definitely be using a regular expression.

Comment: You would use a regular expression to check for a single character?  That's an excessive amount of overhead to get the exact same thing the built in function does.  There are a lot of people who don't understand regex, and generally the simpler answer is the best.

Comment: I would go with `/hello/g.test(your_string)`. While indexOf works, I think a regex test tells a better story of what you're trying to accomplish. If I'm trying to find a sequence of characters inside a string, the index is irrelevant.

Comment: [Docs for indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Answer (score 142):

With ES6 [MDN docs .includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```
"FooBar".includes("oo"); // true

"FooBar".includes("foo"); // false

"FooBar".includes("oo", 2); // false
```

---

E: Not suported by IE - instead you can use the Tilde opperator `~` ([Bitwise NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_NOT))) with [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
~"FooBar".indexOf("oo"); // -2 -> true

~"FooBar".indexOf("foo"); // 0 -> false

~"FooBar".indexOf("oo", 2); // 0 -> false
```

Used with a number, the Tilde operator effective does
`~N => -(N+1)`. Use it with double negation `!!` ([Logical NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!))) to convert the numbers in bools:

```
!!~"FooBar".indexOf("oo"); // true

!!~"FooBar".indexOf("foo"); // false

!!~"FooBar".indexOf("oo", 2); // false
```

Comment: Simple, readable, and returns a boolean. Perfect for when you don't need a regular expression.

Comment: ** Please note that the includes method is not supported by IE **

Comment: The second parameter of `includes` is the `position`, default is 0.

Answer (score 72):

If you have the text in variable `foo`:

```
if (! /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(foo)) {
    // Validation failed
}
```

This will test and make sure the user has entered at least one character, and has entered *only* alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 15):

**ES6** contains inbuilt method ([`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)) in String's `prototype`, which can be used to check if string contains another string or not.

```js
var str = 'To be, or not to be, that is the question.';

console.log(str.includes('To be'));
```

Following polyfill can be used to add this method in non-supported browsers. ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes))

```js
if (!String.prototype.includes) {
  String.prototype.includes = function(search, start) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof start !== 'number') {
      start = 0;
    }
    
    if (start + search.length > this.length) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return this.indexOf(search, start) !== -1;
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You're all thinking too hard. Just use a simple Regular Expression, it's your best friend.

```
var string1 = "Hi Stack Overflow. I like to eat pizza."
var string2 = "Damn, I fail."

var regex = /(pizza)/g // Insert whatever phrase or character you want to find

string1.test(regex); // => true
string2.test(regex); // => false
```

[Learn Regex in 5 minutes?](http://www.regexr.com/)

Comment: So to do something practical with this, you'd simply run it in a selection: `if ( string1.test(regex) ) { alert("He likes pizza!"); }`

Comment: And your alphanumeric test would be... `var regex = /^[a-z0-9]+$/i`

Comment: This is backwards.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test   regexObj.test(str)

Comment: It backwards? `regex.test(string1)`

Comment: Your example methods are backwards. It should be `regex.test(str)`. (`str.match(regex)` is similar, but doesn't return a boolean.)

Answer (score 8):

Use a regular expression to accomplish this.

```
function isAlphanumeric( str ) {
 return /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/.test(str);
}
```

Comment: This will check for exactly *one* digit, and will not accept all alphanumeric characters, as the OP desires.

Comment: @cdhowie.. forgot a +, but i had misread the question as well.. thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 6):

```js
var inputString = "this is home";
var findme = "home";

if ( inputString.indexOf(findme) > -1 ) {
    alert( "found it" );
} else {
    alert( "not found" );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're searching for character(s) in the start or at the end of the string, you can also use `startsWith` and `endsWith`

```
const country = "pakistan";
country.startsWith('p'); // true
country.endsWith('n');  // true
```

Answer (score 5):

To test for alphanumeric characters only:

```
if (/^[0-9A-Za-z]+$/.test(yourString))
{
    //there are only alphanumeric characters
}
else
{
    //it contains other characters
}
```

The regex is testing for 1 or more (+) of the set of characters 0-9, A-Z, and a-z, starting with the beginning of input (^) and stopping with the end of input ($).

Answer (score 5):

Kevins answer is correct but it requires a "magic" number as follows:

```
var containsChar = s.indexOf(somechar) !== -1;
```

In that case you need to know that **-1** stands for *not found*.
I think that a bit better version would be:

```
var containsChar = s.indexOf(somechar) >= 0;
```

Comment: Well according to the [original](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf#page=83), [current](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.indexof), and [draft](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.indexof) standards, `indexOf()` will return *-1* if the string is not found. So it's hardly more *magic* than using *0*.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `string.includes()`. Example:

```js
var string = "lorem ipsum hello world";
var include = "world";
var a = document.getElementById("a");

if (string.includes(include)) {  
  alert("found '" + include + "' in your string");
  a.innerHTML = "found '" + include + "' in your string";
}
```

```html
<p id="a"></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
if ('Hello, World!'.indexOf('orl') !== -1)
    alert("The string 'Hello World' contains the substring 'orl'!");
else
    alert("The string 'Hello World' does not contain the substring 'orl'!");
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/oliverni/cb8xw/

Answer (score 4):

String's search function is useful too. It searches for a character as well as a sub_string in a given string.

`'apple'.search('pl')` returns `2`

`'apple'.search('x')` return `-1`

Answer (score 4):

If you are reading data from the DOM such as a p or h1 tag, for example, you will want to use two native JavaScript functions, it is quiet easy but limited to es6, at least for the solution I am going to provide. I will search all p tags within the DOM, if the text contains a "T" the entire paragraph will be removed. I hope this little example helps someone out!

HTML

```
<p>Text you need to read one</p>
<p>Text you need to read two</p>
<p>Text you need to read three</p>
```

JS

```
let paras = document.querySelectorAll('p');

paras.forEach(p => {
  if(p.textContent.includes('T')){
       p.remove();
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Working perfectly.This exmple will help alot.

```
<script>    
    function check()
    {
       var val = frm1.uname.value;
       //alert(val);
       if (val.indexOf("@") > 0)
       {
          alert ("email");
          document.getElementById('isEmail1').value = true;
          //alert( document.getElementById('isEmail1').value);
       }else {
          alert("usernam");
          document.getElementById('isEmail1').value = false;
          //alert( document.getElementById('isEmail1').value);
       }
    }
</script>

<body>
    <h1>My form </h1>
    <form action="v1.0/user/login" method="post" id = "frm1">
        <p>
            UserName : <input type="text" id = "uname" name="username" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Password : <input type="text" name="password" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="hidden" class="email" id = "isEmail1" name = "isEmail"/>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" id = "submit" value="Add User" onclick="return check();"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

A sample regex pattern test you can use to find out if the string contains a character '**@**':

**/(@[A-Za-z])\w+/.test(str_text)**

Answer (score 0):

**Check if string is alphanumeric or alphanumeric + some allowed chars**

The fastest alphanumeric method is likely as mentioned at: [Best way to alphanumeric check in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434076/best-way-to-alphanumeric-check-in-javascript/25352300#25352300) as it operates on number ranges directly.

Then, to allow a few other extra chars sanely we can just put them [in a `Set`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523436/does-javascript-have-an-implementation-of-a-set-data-structure/24231435#24231435) for fast lookup.

I believe that this implementation will deal with [surrogate pairs correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966476/how-can-i-process-each-letter-of-text-using-javascript/36392879#36392879) correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const assert = require('assert');

const char_is_alphanumeric = function(c) {
  let code = c.codePointAt(0);
  return (
    // 0-9
    (code > 47 && code < 58) ||
    // A-Z
    (code > 64 && code < 91) ||
    // a-z
    (code > 96 && code < 123)
  )
}

const is_alphanumeric = function (str) {
  for (let c of str) {
    if (!char_is_alphanumeric(c)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};

// Arbitrarily defined as alphanumeric or '-' or '_'.
const is_almost_alphanumeric = function (str) {
  for (let c of str) {
    if (
      !char_is_alphanumeric(c) &&
      !is_almost_alphanumeric.almost_chars.has(c)
    ) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};
is_almost_alphanumeric.almost_chars = new Set(['-', '_']);

assert( is_alphanumeric('aB0'));
assert(!is_alphanumeric('aB0_-'));
assert(!is_alphanumeric('aB0_-*'));
assert(!is_alphanumeric('你好'));

assert( is_almost_alphanumeric('aB0'));
assert( is_almost_alphanumeric('aB0_-'));
assert(!is_almost_alphanumeric('aB0_-*'));
assert(!is_almost_alphanumeric('你好'));
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/5b7094fb68e36c2c4af73e8a209a979ebbf32eae/rootfs_overlay/lkmc/nodejs/alphanumeric.js).

Tested in Node.js v10.15.1.

Answer (score 0):

#### It's worked to me!

### Attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”]

This is the most generous of the jQuery attribute selectors that match against a value. It will select an element if the selector's string appears anywhere within the element's attribute value. Compare this selector with the Attribute Contains Word selector (e.g. [attr~="word"]), which is more appropriate in many cases.

source: Attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”] => https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>attributeContains demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<input name="man-news">
<input name="milkman">
<input name="letterman2">
<input name="newmilk">
 
<script>
$( "input[name*='man']" ).val( "has man in it!" );
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: h- how is this supposed to answer the question

Answer (score 0):

The includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(array1.includes(2));
// expected output: true

const pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'bat'];

console.log(pets.includes('cat'));
// expected output: true

console.log(pets.includes('at'));
// expected output: false
```

[know more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)