# check variable if char exist or not

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to tell if a string contains a certain character in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444477/how-to-tell-if-a-string-contains-a-certain-character-in-javascript)

Suppose I have a string in variable ex. `var name="Stackoverflow"`. I want to check in this string if 'z' is exist or not? How can I check this? I don't want to find index or anything else I just want to check if value `z` is exist or not.

Suppose with code. I have a variable.

```
var deleteboxvalue = "1111111111111111111111";
if(!deleteboxvalue.indexOf('z') >= 0){
alert("0 not exist");
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) like this:

```
var name = "Stackoverflow"
var charExists = (name.indexOf('z') >= 0) ? true : false;
alert(charExists);
```

Or just (as pointed out by @Felix Kling):

```
var charExists = (name.indexOf('z') >= 0);
```

Comment: Or just `var charExists = (name.indexOf('z') >= 0);`

Comment: @FelixKling: That's nice short way of doing it. Thanks

Comment: I have modified the question.