# jQuery method to find a character in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

It's on the top of my tongue, but I can't remember the method I would use to scan a string variable for something like a specific character. So for example, I want to check IF var emailaddress CONTAINS the '@' symbol. Can anyone give me some help?

---

Scratch that, indexOf is what I was thinking of.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444477/how-to-tell-if-a-string-contains-a-certain-character-in-javascript

Comment: It is not a jQuery method.

Comment: not everything needs jQuery!

Answer (score 4):

Did you mean indexOf.

```
var email = 'abc@gmail.com';

if(email.indexOf('@')!=-1){
//doLogic
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in jQuery

```
jQuery(function($){
//if the input type email contains the @
if( $('input[type="email"]:contains("@")') )
{

alert( $(this).val() ); 

}
else ...

});
```