# jQuery detect if string contains something

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write jQuery code to detect if a live string contains a specific set of characters then the string alerts me.

**HTML**

```
<textarea class="type"></textarea>
```

**My Jquery**

```
$('.type').keyup(function() {
    var v = $('.type').val();
    if ($('.type').is(":contains('> <')")){
        console.log('contains > <');        
    }
    console.log($('.type').val());
});
```

if for example I typed the following

```
> <a href="http://google.com">Google</a> <a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
```

My code should console log alert me that there > < present in the string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444477/how-to-tell-if-a-string-contains-a-certain-character-in-javascript

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do? The answers below does exactly what you ask for, but there might be a better way to go depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Use indexOf it will be faster also

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could use `String.prototype.indexOf` to accomplish that. Try something like this:

```js
$('.type').keyup(function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  if (v.indexOf('> <') !== -1) {
    console.log('contains > <');
  }
  console.log(v);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="type"></textarea>
```

**Update**

Modern browsers also have a [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method.

Answer (score 7):

You get the value of the textarea, use it :

```
$('.type').keyup(function() {
    var v = $('.type').val(); // you'd better use this.value here
    if (v.indexOf('> <')!=-1) {
       console.log('contains > <');        
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use javascript's indexOf function.

```
var str1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
var str2 = "DEFG";
if(str1.indexOf(str2) != -1){
   alert(str2 + " found");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use Contains of jquery [Contains](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)
like this

```
if ($('.type:contains("> <")').length > 0)
{
 //do stuffs to change 
}
```