# Is there any problem in my code? (Simple JavaScript find Special Char)

Tags: javascript

i want to get two msgs when user type special character like m@rk @l@n
with the help of charCodeAt();

my code gives an repeated answer if i enter normal text or if i enter spec char it gives my both condition true

```
var username = prompt("Enter Username");
var boolean = true;

for(var i=0;i<username.length;i++){

  if(username[i].charCodeAt()==33 || username[i].charCodeAt()==44 || username[i].charCodeAt()==46 || username[i].charCodeAt()==64){
        document.write("Wrong input: "+username);
        boolean=true;
        break;
  }
  else{
       document.write("correct input "+username);
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if a string contains a certain character in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444477/how-to-tell-if-a-string-contains-a-certain-character-in-javascript)

Comment: I would avoid using `boolean` as a variable name since it's a future reserved keyword from an older ECMAScript spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Future_reserved_keywords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `document.write` outside of the loop:

```js
var username = prompt("Enter Username");
    var valid = true;
    
    for(var i=0;i<username.length;i++){
    
      if(username[i].charCodeAt()==33 || username[i].charCodeAt()==44 || username[i].charCodeAt()==46 || username[i].charCodeAt()==64){
            valid=false;
            break;
      }
    }
    document.write((valid?"Correct input ":"Wrong input ")+username);
```

Comment: not working properly .. when i enter special character it will show me a message "Correct input" ... but this input container spec char :|

Comment: @NoobDev Which special character? I tried with `@` (as it is in your example), and it is working.