# Circular progress bar based on percentage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm working on a js code where circular progress bar shows based on ratings. But there's an issue. Now total value is `10` set for progress bar. So I can enter max `10` in here. If I enter `9%`, it not works as because max-value is 10. But I want something like that, if I enter any number with percent, like that `70%` `85%` `35%`, the the value / max value will work as `100`. How can I do it ?

When I enter any number below `10` and without percentage, it looks like that:[image: Without Percentage and Below 10]

When enter with percentage: [image: With Percentage]

I want that, if the number is with any percentage, the circle or progress bar will consider as 100 max value. And if Don't have any percent after Number, it will work as 10 max value.

Here's my code:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      let val = $(".ratings").html();
      const progressBar = $('[role="progressbar"]');
      progressBar.attr('aria-valuenow', val); // Set the value to aria-valuenow attribute
      progressBar.css('--value', val); // Set the value to --value CSS custom property
      progressBar.text(val);
    });
```

```css
div[role="progressbar"] {
      --size: 3rem;
      --fg: #369;
      --bg: #def;
      --pgValue: var(--value);
      --pgPercentage: calc(var(--pgValue) * 10);
      width: var(--size);
      height: var(--size);
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: grid;
      place-items: center;
      background: 
        radial-gradient(closest-side, white 80%, transparent 0 99.9%, white 0),
        conic-gradient(var(--fg) calc(var(--pgPercentage) * 1%), var(--bg) 0);
      font-size: calc(var(--size) / 3.5);
      color: var(--fg);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ratings" style="display: none;">9.5</div>
    <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="10" style="--value:"></div>
```

Comment: what happens it some one has 10.5 value without %?

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant if someone enter any value more than `10`, it will show `10`. I mean more than `10` or `10` is same. It will show you the number `10.5`, but progress bar will be full. 

Like That : https://prnt.sc/nCtp323nOmpJ

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant But I wanted both system, Like if I want any number without % sign, it will work as now (Max Value is 10) like 5/7.5/10/3.7. But if I enter any number with % sign, it will work as max value 100. Both features. If the number convey %, it will work like 100, and if any solid number, it will work like 10 max value

Comment: that means 35 will be assumed as 10 but same 35 % needs to be shown in ration of 100%?

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant Exactly. 100% Right. Finally Somabody can catch my words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just modify the code and use 2 progress bar - 1 for percentage value and other without percentage. Code for progressbar could be same as I want to show how to handle both value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      let val_str = val = $(".ratings1").html();
      if(val.includes('%')) {
          val = val.replace(/%\s*$/, "");
          val = "" + (parseInt(val) / 10);
      }
          
      const progressBar = $('[class="progressbar1"]');
      progressBar.attr('aria-valuenow', val); // Set the value to aria-valuenow attribute
      progressBar.css('--value', val); // Set the value to --value CSS custom property
      progressBar.text(val_str);
      
      
      let val_str2 = val2 = $(".ratings2").html();
      if(val2.includes('%')) {
          val2 = val2.replace(/%\s*$/, "");
          val2 = "" + (parseInt(val2) / 10);
      }
          
      const progressBar2 = $('[class="progressbar2"]');
      progressBar2.attr('aria-valuenow', val2); // Set the value to aria-valuenow attribute
      progressBar2.css('--value', val2); // Set the value to --value CSS custom property
      progressBar2.text(val_str2);
    });
```

```css
div[role="progressbar"] {
      --size: 3rem;
      --fg: #369;
      --bg: #def;
      --pgValue: var(--value);
      --pgPercentage: calc(var(--pgValue) * 10);
      width: var(--size);
      height: var(--size);
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: grid;
      place-items: center;
      background: 
        radial-gradient(closest-side, white 80%, transparent 0 99.9%, white 0),
        conic-gradient(var(--fg) calc(var(--pgPercentage) * 1%), var(--bg) 0);
      font-size: calc(var(--size) / 3.5);
      color: var(--fg);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ratings1" style="display: none;">9.5</div>
    <div class="progressbar1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="10" style="--value:"></div>
    
<br/><br/>
<div class="ratings2" style="display: none;">95%</div>
    <div class="progressbar2" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="10" style="--value:"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Yogendra Your answer is 90% closer to my question. But Can't I do it in same class ? I mean in your code, you have added 2 class `ratings1` and `ratings2` But can't we do it just usong one class ? For seperation, it will use js.jquery method to check whether there's a `%` is present or not.

Comment: @Md.Ibrahim, you can do it using single I have used 2 progress-bar to show you how data will show. As per the code Both progess-bar handling both value percentage and without percentage. You can just copy my code snippet and check by swapping the value

Comment: OH. Thanks. I got my answer. Thanks Again

Answer (score 1):

So instead of `9.5`, you want that div element to contain `95%`?

Then you first need to convert your percentage to the 0 to 10 "range" - which in this case is of course terribly easy, you divide the 95 by 10 - after you used `parseInt` first, to get only the 95 as a numeric value out of the `95%`.

And then the second thing that is important here, is the *type* of your CSS variable. It needs to be a string value - and as long as you just read the value from the input field, it was one. But now that we did a bit of math, it is a float value, that needs to be made into a string value again - which we can f.e. do using the old `"" + ...` trick.

(I introduced a second variable `displayVal` that will keep the original `95%` text from the div, because that's what you want to show inside the circle.)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      let displayVal = $(".ratings").html(),
          val = "" + (parseInt(displayVal) / 10);
      const progressBar = $('[role="progressbar"]');
      progressBar.attr('aria-valuenow', val); // Set the value to aria-valuenow attribute
      progressBar.css('--value', val); // Set the value to --value CSS custom property
      progressBar.text(displayVal);
    });
```

```css
div[role="progressbar"] {
      --size: 3rem;
      --fg: #369;
      --bg: #def;
      --pgValue: var(--value);
      --pgPercentage: calc(var(--pgValue) * 10);
      width: var(--size);
      height: var(--size);
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: grid;
      place-items: center;
      background: 
        radial-gradient(closest-side, white 80%, transparent 0 99.9%, white 0),
        conic-gradient(var(--fg) calc(var(--pgPercentage) * 1%), var(--bg) 0);
      font-size: calc(var(--size) / 3.5);
      color: var(--fg);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ratings" style="display: none;">95%</div>
    <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="10" style="--value:"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. I really appreciate your response. But What I wanted is that, According to my question, Now total progress value is 10. I mean Its max value is 10. Any number like 5, 9, 3 or 10 is accepted, but not more 10. But when I enter with any percentagen it not works. 

I wanted both system, Like if I want any number without `%` sign, it will work as now (Max Value is 10) like 5/7.5/10/3.7. But if I enter any number with `%` sign, it will work as max value `100`. Both features. If the number convey `%`, it will work like `100`, and if any solid number, it will work like `10` max value.

Comment: So add a check whether the text you read from the div element contains a `%` first, and then handle each case accordingly.

Comment: How can I do a check ?

`It means 35 will be assumed as 10 but same 35 % needs to be shown in ration of 100%?`

Comment: Please do a bit of your own research, before immediately asking "how can I do that"; especially when it comes to things this trivial, and already broadly discussed. "javascript check if text contains specific character" typed into Google can lead you to results such as https://stackoverflow.com/q/4444477/1427878 in no time-